# Create json object in SQL stored procedure based on input parameters

Tags: sql, json

I need to create a json object in a stored procedure based on input parameters. The following works, but it's not very elegant and I am looking for a more elegant solution.

```
-- adding log entry
declare @logjson nvarchar(max); 

set @logjson = concat(       '{"InputParameters":[', '{');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"MacOwner":"', @Owner, '",');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"EMS":"', @EMS, '",');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"AXBomId":"', @AXBomId, '",');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"Serial":"', @SerialId, '",');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"Device":"', @AXItem, '",');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"HWDevice":"', @HWDevice, '",');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"TestPCHostName":"', @TestPCHostName, '",');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"TestSWVersion":"', @TestSWVersion, '"');  --Last parameter no comma
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '}],');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"OutputParameters":[','{');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '"MACAddress":"', @MACAddress, '"');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '}');
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, ']' );
set @logjson = concat(@logjson, '}');
```

I tried to use the `SELECT xxxxx FOR JSON AUTO` - but this requires at least one table in the select statement.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? JSON support is **highly** vendor-specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select from a subquery. For example

```
declare @Owner varchar(5) ='ow123', @AXBomId int =11

select * from (
   select @Owner as MacOwner,  @AXBomId as AXBomId
) t
for json auto
```

returns

```
[{"MacOwner":"ow123","AXBomId":11}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - why didn't I think of this :-) :-)   Have a nice day